# Pandas groupby multiple columns, sum and append answer as new column to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({"AAA":["x1","x1","x1","x1"],
              "BBB":["y1","y1","y1","y2"],
              "CCC":["t1","t2","t3","t1"],
              "DDD":[10,11,18,17]})

Out[1]:
  AAA BBB CCC  DDD
0  x1  y1  t1   10
1  x1  y1  t2   11
2  x1  y1  t3   18
3  x1  y2  t1   17
```

I want to sum the values in column `"DDD"` for the groups defined by `groupby(["AAA","BBB"])`.

So:

1. row 0 `(x1, y1, t1, 10)`, row 1 `(x1, y1, t2, 11)`, row 2 `(x1, y1, t3, 18)` are one group.
2. I want to add a new column to the dataframe summing the "DDD" column
3. so my row vectors will become:
4. row 0 `(x1, y1, t1, 10, 39)`, row 1 `(x1, y1, t2, 11, 39)`, row 2 `(x1, y1, t3, 18, 39)`

I want to have a new column with the values for these group by operations. I want the following dataframe:

```
In [2]:
pd.DataFrame({"AAA":["x1","x1","x1","x1"],
              "BBB":["y1","y1","y1","y2"],
              "CCC":["t1","t2","t3","t1"],
              "DDD":[10,11,18,17],
              "AAA_BBB_sum":[39,39,39,17]})
Out[2]:
  AAA  AAA_BBB_sum BBB CCC  DDD
0  x1           39  y1  t1   10
1  x1           39  y1  t2   11
2  x1           39  y1  t3   18
3  x1           17  y2  t1   17
```

How is best to do this?

One way I have thought of (but am struggling to implement) is:

1. create a new column which is the concatenation of `AAABBB` so that
   they're unique
2. group by `AAA` and `DDD` so I can still select the
   `AAABBB` column
3. create a sum of `DDD` for each group
4. use this as a 'lookup' table to insert the value to new column based on matching `AAABBB` columns

I'm sure there must be a better way. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Use `df['AAA_BBB sum'] = df.groupby(['AAA', 'BBB'])['DDD'].transform('sum')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use:

```
df['AAA_BBB sum'] = df.groupby(['AAA', 'BBB'])['DDD'].transform(lambda x: x.sum())
```

This gives:

```
    AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  AAA_BBB sum
0    x1   y1   t1   10           39
1    x1   y1   t2   11           39
2    x1   y1   t3   18           39
3    x1   y2   t1   17           17
```